# MVC3 - 'Element 'link' cannot be nested within element 'link'' - trying to add page specific CSS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a layout page thusly

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/content/main_layout.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/content/menu.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    @RenderSection("JS", required:false)
    @RenderSection("CSS", required:false)
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

And then a view like so

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
    Layout = "~/views/shared/_layout.cshtml";
}
@using RS.Common.HtmlHelpers;
@section JS
{
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/fue.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery.flexslider-min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
@section CSS 
{
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/content/hp.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/content/hp_form.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/content/flexslider.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
}

<h4>Test!</h4>
```

The page loads fine as I expect. However, I am getting 3 warnings:

```
Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): Element 'link' cannot be nested within element 'link'
```

This error, one for each of the  tags in the CSS section on the view.

It is only really an annoyance at this stage, but I wondered what the cause (and thus solution) for this error might be?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have specified HTML5 DOCTYPE and yet trying to validate as `XHTML 1.0 Transitional`. I suppose that the final rendered HTML looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="/content/main_layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/content/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="/scripts/fue.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/jquery.flexslider-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link href="/content/hp.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/content/hp_form.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/content/flexslider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h4>Test!</h4>
</body>
</html>
```

You might want to invert the order of the two `RenderSection` in your layout so that the links and scripts are grouped together. Or you might also consider moving the script declarations to the end of the page:

Like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/content/main_layout.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/content/menu.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    @RenderSection("CSS", required:false)
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    @RenderSection("JS", required:false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is indeed the reason and the layout looks much clearer, too. Thanks again Darin.